# OpenOPC.OPCError: Dispatch: Invalid class string

Tags: python, opc

I want to operate the KEPWareEx through python. I installed the openOPC library in python and tried to access the OPCclient. I got the above error.

Comment: Can you post relevant code/command you're using to run the client.

Comment: I am referring `http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html` document. I used the same command which is given in the documentation for creating the client. like opc = OpenOPC.client()

Answer (score 1):

for connection to kepware we need to install 
1: OPC python library
2: Opc gateway from https://www.matrikonopc.com/downloads/index.aspx
3: OPC Kepware software.

Follow the commands from 
http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html.